# Use PHP to search based on conditions and show form based on results

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to use PHP to accept user input and search based on a code that they will have assigned to them so they can register for a course online. Once they search their code it will display on the same page results. I haven't really worked a lot with PHP and am trying to figure this out. I have tried different things I have seen but can't get it to work. The below code is what I am testing and not actually what it will be once completed.

```
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="UserSubmission">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<?php
 $U = UserSubmission;

 if ($U = "MJPJPL0509")   

    <form action="mailto:someone@somewhere.com" method="post"> 
        Full Name:<br>
        <input type:"text" name="name">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>



?>
```

Comment: Can be in ajax html and php?

Comment: @JoseMarques I guess it could

Comment: You use database or not?If so, which one?

Comment: @JoseMarques no im not using a database simply because I don't expect very many people to respond, maybe 30 max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should  work. Check out the comments

```
<?php

// added in echo for php script.
//form should have method and action.
echo '<form method = "POST" action = "#">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="UserSubmission">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>'; 


if(isset($_POST['UserSubmission'])){

 //naming convention of $U : best practice should be $u
 $U = $_POST['UserSubmission'];

 // in your code, it shows: if($U = "MJPJPL0509") , it should be if($U == "MJPJPL0509"). Because you are comparing the string not assiging a variable.
 if ($U == "MJPJPL0509") {

    echo '<form action="mailto:someone@somewhere.com" method="post"> 
        Full Name:<br>
        <input type:"text" name="name">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>';


    }

}



?>
```

Comment: This works exactly as I need. Thank you for saving my butt :)!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what your problem is and I am not a god of PHP but...

HTML forms do a POST of their input field data. To get hold of that in the PHP script you do $_POST["form_item_name_not_ID"]. You probably want to ensure this is not null and so forth with your normal validation on front and back ends.

next, assuming you are using MySQL and have already setup the server for it, you can just follow steps from here:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

You can use fetch assoc to recursively loop the mysql results which will be associative arrays - essentially the same thing as JSON in that they are key value pairs. Be warned that the function does not return some object you can loop, it appears to recursively do stuff so you cant just try and output this.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

HTML forms will refresh the page you are on after the post so if you want to alter the page content I would personally not submit a form but use ajax instead to post to your PHP script. This way you can simply echo a variable and the ajax success section will recieve it. This can just be a string of html.

Finally to help you write your HTML in your PHP script you can use HEREDOC so you can write in a readable way. Its super simple and here is an example:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc